# jsFiddle Throws Console Error

Tags: javascript, mootools, jsfiddle

I am an experienced developer, but I am new to JavaScript.
Having an issue with JavaScript, I decided to use jsFiddle, which is also new to me.

I found this tutorial:
http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html

This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/richardpaulhall/y540ozwv/10/

```
-----
<div id='test'>Helloooo World!</div>
-----
$('test').addEvent('click', (function() {
$('test').set('html', 'Goodbye World!')
$('test').fade('out');
}));
-----
```

I set up the example as directed, but it did not work.
It throws console errors.

fiddle.jshell.net/richardpaulhall/y540ozwv/10/show/:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of null

Line 51:  $('test').addEvent('click', (function() {

The tutorial mentions setting the framework to Mootools. I chose 1.3.2

The tutorial used the alpha version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fiddle`, you need to change the `LOAD TYPE` to `onDomReady`. (You can change this by clicking on the settings icon on the top-right corner of the javascript window). Now your `js` will run only when the DOM is ready or all HTML elements are loaded.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y540ozwv/13/)

Comment: That fixed the problem.
But one sets _LOADTYPE_ in the Settings page of the JAVASCRIPT pane.

Comment: @ThePascalKing yes of course :). Totally forgot about that other settings icon on top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jQuery:

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Then update js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#test').on('click', function() {
     $('#test').html('Goodbye World!');
     $('#test').fadeOut('slow');
   });
});
```

Ah, sorry, you are not using jQuery...